# Nhibernate Criteria retrieve child of parent with restriction on other child of parent

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I need to be able to write the following query as a Criteria.

```
SELECT hist.*
FROM
    Administration admin
    INNER JOIN Item item ON item.AdministrationId = admin.AdministrationId
    INNER JOIN ItemHistory hist ON hist.ItemId = item.ItemId
WHERE
    item.itemId = @param
    and hist.IsError =
        (
            SELECT (CASE status.errorType
                        WHEN 'Warning' THEN 0
                        ELSE 1
                    END
                   )
            FROM
                AdminStatus status
            WHERE
                status.AdministrationId = admin.AdministrationId
                AND status.Group = 'Issues'
        )
```

I'm pretty sure I'll need to do the sub query as a detached criteria:

```
var status = DetachedCriteria.For<AdminStatus>("status");
        status.CreateAlias("status.Administration", "admin");
        status.Add(Restrictions.Eq("status.Group", "Issues"));
        status.SetProjection(Projections.Property("AdministrationId"));
        status.SetProjection(Projections.Conditional(
                        Restrictions.Eq("status.errorType", "Warning"),
                        Projections.Constant(0),
                        Projections.Constant(1)));
```

But I'm not sure how to join that with my primary criteria:

```
    var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<ItemHIstory>("hist");
        criteria.CreateAlias("ItemHistory.Item", "item");
        criteria.CreateAlias("item.Administration", "admin");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I'm not sure how to join that with my primary criteria:

Methods from `Subqueries` class glue detached sub-query with main criteria. `Subqueries.PropertyEq` in you case:

```
var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<ItemHIstory>("hist");
criteria.CreateAlias("ItemHistory.Item", "item");
criteria.CreateAlias("item.Administration", "admin");
criteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyEq("hist.IsError ", status))
```

And regarding detached criteria. Alias creation seems unnecessary:

```
var status = DetachedCriteria.For<AdminStatus>("status");

status.Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("status.AdministrationId", "admin.AdministrationId"));
status.Add(Restrictions.Eq("status.Group", "Issues"));

status.SetProjection(Projections.Conditional(
                Restrictions.Eq("status.errorType", "Warning"),
                Projections.Constant(0),
                Projections.Constant(1)));
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  I just don't understand the statement "Methods from Subqueries class glue detached sub-query with main criteria."

Comment: Just meant that there are many methods in Subqueries class that can be used to join main criteria with subquery.